# below given error coming in my android studio at run time

Tags: android

`eglMakeCurrent` failed and

> android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:2744 error 0x501

error coming. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code and your **full** logcat.

Comment: Error:(22, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Tkd_soap' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>